# Text rotate bluring

Tags: html, layout, css

I am trying to rotate some text 90 degrees anticlockwise..

So far the only way seems to be to use the DXImageTransform filter.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

See the following live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzSZE/1/

When viewing this in IE8 the text is blurred almost beyond comprehension:

[image]

In IE writing-mode can rotate clockwise fine without any artifacts but not anticlockwise! So this feels like the rendering engine must be able to do it.

What am I missing? Is there any way to rotate text in this way in IE without this bluring artifact?

I only need to support IE8+ if that helps.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your jsfiddle link works for me on IE8 / Windows 7. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. Are you sure you have set the browser mode to IE8, and the text is rendering with no bluring artifact?

Comment: I am using the actual IE8, not IE9 in dev mode. http://i.imgur.com/gpbiU.png

Comment: Looks fine for me in IE7 and 8 on XP

Comment: Strange, I am on IE9 in IE8 mode... http://i.imgur.com/sf2Wj.png , I also still see the blurring in normal mode!

Comment: @Chris I notice that you are running IE9, with IE8 browser mode and document mode, but for me (actually running IE8 itself) I am getting compatibility view, which is essentially falling back to IE6. I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you see is not blurring, but text pixelation. When a filter is applied, in some combinations of IE/WinOS, **the text anti-aliasing get switched off** producing the corrupt-looking image.